# Calling a Non Module Class from a Module Class in java 9

Tags: java, java-9, java-module

I am trying to call a non-module class from a module class. I have created a folder structure

```
moduledemo > allclasses > moduleC > packageC > MyMethods.class
```

is the path to my module class file

```
moduledemo > moduleC > packageC > MyMethods.java
```

and

```
moduledemo > nomodule > packageD > DemoNoModule.class
```

is the no module class that I am calling from `MyMethods.java`

I am able to compile the DemoNoModule file. I am able to compile MyMethods.java into allclasses folder `moduleC`.

When I am running MyMethods I am getting error ***moduleC not found***. Can anyone update? I am using the following command to run

```
java --module-path allclasses -m moduleC/packageC.MyMethods
```

Both files code -> Non-Module Class

```
package packageD;

public class DemoNoModule {
    public void showD() {
        System.out.println("this is show of D in No Module");
    }
}
```

Module class calling class

```
package packageC;
import packageD.*;

public class MyMethods {
    public static void main(String s[]) {
        DemoNoModule d=new DemoNoModule();
        d.showD();
    }
}
```

Module info in module C

```
module moduleC {    
    exports packageC; 
}
```

[image]

Comment: What is your module-info for moduleC?

Comment: added above. but it does not have any role in this.

Comment: If packageD.DemoNoModule is on the class path then the module in the question will compile and run but it needs `--add-modules moduleC=ALL-UNNAMED`. This is because named modules don't read unnamed modules by default.

Comment: @AlanBateman I assume you mean `--add-reads`?

Comment: Sorry yes, a typo in my comment.

Comment: @AlanBateman where do i write --add-reads moduleC=ALL-UNNAMED. Even after adding this to the java command i get the same error - moduleC not found.

Comment: The command line has been updated in the question to include --add-reads but there seems to be another issue, moduleC is not observable. Can the question be updated to show the contents of the allclasses directory? (btw: `java --module-path allclasses --list-modules` will list all obervable modules and may you to diagnose this issue).

Comment: Thanks @AlanBateman

Answer (score 1):

On one hand, the `moduleC`(mind improving naming?) is a named module.

While on another, the "no module class" termed by you is nothing but as [stated by Alan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48365299/calling-a-non-module-class-from-a-module-class-in-java-9#comment83717691_48365299) a class present on the classpath. The classes present on the classpath during the execution are part of an [unnamed module in JPMS](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jigsaw/spec/sotms/#the-unnamed-module).

Quoting the documentation further:-

> The unnamed module *exports all of its packages.* This enables
>   flexible migration... It does not, however, mean
>   that code in a named module can access types in the unnamed module. A
>   *named module cannot, in fact, even declare a dependence upon the
>   unnamed module*.

This is intentional to preserve the reliable configuration in the module system. As stated further :

> If a *package is defined in both a named module and the unnamed module
>   then the package in the unnamed module is ignored*. This preserves
>   reliable configuration even in the face of the chaos of the class
>   path, ensuring that every module still reads at most one module
>   defining a given package.

Still, to make use of a class from the unnamed module in your named module `moduleC`, you can follow the suggestion of making use of the flag to add ALL-UNNAMED module to be [read by modules](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/261#Increasing-readability) on the module path using the 
following command:

```
--add-reads <source-module>=<target-module> // moduleC=ALL-UNNAMED
```

> As a special case, if the `<target-module>` is `ALL-UNNAMED` then
>   readability edges will be added from the source module to all present
>   and future unnamed modules, *including that corresponding to the class
>   path.*

**PS**: Do take into consideration the highlighted portion(above) of the documentation as you do so.

Also note the long-term solution would be to revise your design here, for which you can plan to move your code in the class `DemoNoModule` into an *explicit module* or package it separately to be converted into an *automatic module*.

Comment: It is not a commercial code. i am just trying to learn how modules work in java. Even after adding --add-reads as below java --module-path allclasses --all-reads moduleC=ALL-UNNAMED -m moduleC/packageC.MyMethods it is still giving error moduleC not found

Comment: @user2779311 In that case, could you share a reproducible code or screenshot of your project structure or complete stack trace of the error you get using debug logs enabled?

Comment: The project structure is already given in problem. screen shot of when i am running the java command is attached.

Answer (score 0):

Java 9 programs are supposed to be modular. That is how I understood jigsaw in JDK-9. So, IMHO, you'll have to 'wrap' your packageD in another module and in the module-info for moduleC write `requires moduleD`. Also `moduleD` should export packageD.
`ALL-UNNAMED` is added for backward compatibility, and I suppose it will be removed in some point of Java evolution.